# Enabling Awstats for only one website?

Tags: linux

I remember disabling awstats on my dedicated server because it overloaded pretty bad. Now I was wondering if there's a way to enable it for only ONE of the websites hosted on this server (the site has a dedicated ip). And since it doesn't have much traffic I think it wont overload.

Is there a way to do this? I use whm/cpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a config file just for that website, awstats.websitenamehere.conf - that should do it.